# Check if given string is interleaved of two other string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

I wrote the code for checking if S3 is a interleaving of S1 and S2 string.

But it fails for simple strings like "AB" , "CD" -> "ACBD"

Am I missing something ?

```
class InterleavedString {

    // error
    public static boolean isInterleaved (String A, String B, String C)
    {
        // Iterate through all characters of C.
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
        while (C != null)
        {
            // Match first character of C with first character of A,
            // If matches them move A to next 
            if (A.charAt(a) == C.charAt(c))
                a++;

            // Else Match first character of C with first character of B,
            // If matches them move B to next 
            else if (B.charAt(b) == C.charAt(c))
                b++;

            // If doesn't match with either A or B, then return false
            else
                return false;

            // Move C to next for next iteration
            c++;
        }

        // If A or B still have some characters, then length of C is smaller 
        // than sum of lengths of A and B, so return false
        if (A != null || B != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String A = "AB", B = "CD", C = "ACBD";
        System.out.println(isInterleaved(A, B, C));
    }
}
```

ERROR :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 2  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   strings.InterleavedString.isInterleaved(InterleavedString.java:14)    at
>   strings.InterleavedString.main(InterleavedString.java:40)

**EDITED :**

```
while (c != C.length())
.....
.....
if (a != A.length() || b != B.length())
```

Comment: Also .. is my code the most efficient one ? or could this be improved ?

Comment: *"Am I missing something?"* Yes; the end of your array.

Comment: If A and C don't have any common characters, this code will keep walking through the characters in A until you receive an index out of range exception (since you ran out of characters).  There are other problems with the code, but that is what is causing the error in question.

Comment: What should a correct algorithm return for this problem for this set of input: `A=abd, B=dc, C=abdcd` ? _TRUE_ or _FALSE_ ?

Answer (score 3):

The condition of your `while` statement is wrong. You are never changing your value of `C`. Instead of `while (C != null)` you should use while `c != C.length()` or something similar.

The same problem is with your `A != null` and `B != null` statements because `charAt` does not remove any characters!

In addition you need to check the bounds of your `Strings` in your `if` clauses:

```
if (a < A.length() && A.charAt(a) == C.charAt(c))
```

Also if you are aiming for efficiency you should add this check at the beginning of your method and in turn remove the last `if` statement:

```
if (A.length() + B.length() != C.length())
    return false;
```

Comment: I changed as per your suggestions...still it throws the same error

Comment: does this approach works for `A=abd`, `B=dc`, `C=abdcd`? I doubt :)

Comment: @Fallen true enough :) however, I wasn't actually designing an optimal solution but helping the OP with the most basic problems at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong .. Try with "XXY", "XXZ", "XXZXXY" .. The output will be false

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean interleaving(String s1, String s2, String s3){
        char a[] = s1.toCharArray();
        char b[] = s2.toCharArray();
        char c[] = s3.toCharArray();

        if(a.length+b.length!=c.length){
            return false;
        }

        int i=0,j=0,k=0;

        while(k<=c.length-1){
           if(i<a.length && c[k]==a[i]){
               i++;
           }else if(j<b.length && c[k]==b[j]){
               j++;
           }else{
               return false;
           }
           k++;
        }

        return true;
    }
```